# How to send code to Team Foundation Server w/out Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a client that I have to send my ASP.NET project to their Team Foundation Server (its a 'Web Site' not a 'Project')  First, does it being a 'Web Site' not a 'Project' matter?  It was created in Visual Web Developer Express Edition, I don't have Visual Studio.  Second, I don't have Team Foundation Server or any Team components.  I just need to send my project to their server, that's it.

Is there any way to do this without having TFS and/or Visual Studio?  Is there any 'Express' or 'Free' Team Foundation Server component that I can use to do this?  I have searched but to no avail.  Any help/suggestions are GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KudzoWorld did all the work for me:

```
http://www.kudzuworld.com/blogs/Tech/TFSClients.en.aspx
```

The TortoiseSVN Bridge looks cool though.

```
http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge
```

Comment: Thanks, got the TortoiseSVN Bridge and seems to be working (I think my client messed up my Login/Password though, so I still can't connect but I think it should work, its asking for authentication)  I already use TotroiseSVN for PHP projects so this worked out well... I didn't know it existed though!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the [TFS Powertools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).  These provide a way to do check in / out from within windows explorer just like TortoiseSVN.

It's called the Windows Shell Extension.

Scratch that.  I just realized that you don't have the TFS client installed.  The power tools require it.

Have them send you the client.  In order for you to access their server they have to have an open TFS Client Access License anyway.

Incidentally, you can download the [TFS client from codeplex](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Obtaining%20the%20Team%20Explorer%20Client&referringTitle=Home)